# How to read from port#### on home IP 127.0.0.1

Tags: c#, sockets, udp, port

I have a program that sends data to the home IP to the port####.

I want to access this and make it readable data. Maybe in C#?

I haven't tried doing this before and I have only a vague idea of doing sockets.

The program I'm trying access is a UDP. Therefore it's a UDP port reader I need to incorporate on another program.

"####" < is just any random number.

Comment: have you tried an internet search for "C# socket programming" ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a listener on your Home PC to listen on the port ####

and perform a while loop to accept incoming connections.

Check out [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397809.aspx)

You may need to specify your own high-level communication protocol, example?

**Message structure:**

01:UserID:MessageText

**General Command:**

02:UserID:CommandCode

...etc.

You get it, right? Specify an identifier or a keyword to recognize the type of the incoming message and then process the message with a suitable handler.

Network Programming is Fun!

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'll try this as well. :D